# Is there a php port of namick/obfuscate_id rails plugin ?

Tags: php, laravel

Please check this 
https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id
This plugin converts id 7000 to 5270192353

I tried https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php and it similar ones but it converts ids into a mix of alphabets like (yJJpo90) and numbers.I don't want that.I want IDs to convert into a positive integers.Are there any php packages for this sort?

Comment: Fork that library and create your own version according to your requirements. Within the library, [`Hashids.php`](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php/blob/master/lib/Hashids/Hashids.php), change the alphabet as `private $_alphabet = 1234567890';` and use it?

Comment: I don't want to change it.I have no idea about encryption and what kind of problems changing this would cause in the future.I would like to see an existing package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **Optimus id transformation**:

> With this library, you can transform your internal id's to obfuscated integers based on Knuth's integer hash. It is similar to Hashids, but **will generate integers instead of random strings**. It is also super fast.

https://github.com/jenssegers/optimus