# hide passed IDs in URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

noob question. when I pass an `id` in the route to query my DB, is there a way to prevent the actual `id` from showing in the URL in browser.

If not, is there a way to prevent the user from changing the `id` in the URL and access other information?

Some sort of validation you get from clicking the link on the previous page or something.

I hope this make sense.

Comment: You need a middleware to check if the id in question is owned by the user. You can also obfuscate the id, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31101771/2094178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve your record with an hash instead of the id directly.

You can use package like https://github.com/mitchellvanw/hashids (there must be some others)

Also, if you just want to hide it, you can POST it to your page. Don't forget that users can still change the form informations.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode` to hide url from users and preventing them to change.